# Extrapolating from the significant difference between two continuous variables

Tags: regression, t-test, descriptive-statistics, model

If we have two continuous variables, the same variable in fact, one before an intervention and the other after, and we then see by a paired t-test that there is a significant difference between the two...

...And we want to create a variable for the observations called "had a significant effect" which is then a binary no/yes variable, to be included in another model.

How would we go by figuring out which observations had a significant difference to construct our binary "had an effect" variable?

Comment: This is a wrong use of the word "significant", at least referring to significance tests by standard statistical standards. Significance is a feature of a full sample with respect to a hypothesis in terms of a test statistic. It is not a feature of a single observation.

Comment: So I have to define myself what I consider to be "an effect"? In other words I have to define, say 20% difference means the drug had an effect?

Comment: I can't tell you what you "have to do", particularly because I don't know why you have to reduce information to binary in the first place.

Comment: That's true, thank you.

Comment: Keep it up @Paze ! I remember you because we started getting active on this forum around the same time and I remember your questions and picture. Just wanted to give you some encouragement on your stats journey!

Comment: Thank you Huy! This place is a godsend!